# How to Get Values Not Contained In Table From Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to get a list of country values for a product that don't exist in another table of "excluded" countries.

For example, my table of excluded values looks like:

**LocationRestrictions**

| productID | locationCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 1 | DEF |
| 1 | GHI |
| 2 | ABC |
| 2 | GHI |
| 3 | JKL |

So basically all countries in **Locations** except any contained in **LocationRestrictions** table. The only issue is my **Locations** table does not have an ID column:

**Locations**

| locationCode |
| --- |
| ABC |
| DEF |
| GHI |
| JKL |
| MNO |
| PQR |
| STU |
| VWX |
| YZ |

My current code looks like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      productid,
      locationcode,
      Location
INTO #temp
FROM LabelRestrictions
WHERE productid = 1

SELECT locationcode, location 
INTO #temp2
FROM Locations

SELECT DISTINCT
    t2.location,
    t2.locationcode
FROM #temp2 t2
WHERE t2.locationcode NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t1.locationcode FROM #temp t1)
```

Which returns something like:

| locationCode |
| --- |
| JKL |
| MNO |
| PQR |
| STU |
| VWX |
| YZ |

But this only works if I specify the *productid* in the first SELECT statement and otherwise will return nothing.

What I'm looking for is something like:

| productID | locationCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | JKL |
| 1 | MNO |
| 1 | PQR |
| 1 | STU |
| 1 | VWX |
| 1 | YZ |
| 2 | DEF |
| 2 | JKL |
| 2 | MNO |
| 2 | PQR |
| 2 | STU |
| 2 | VWX |
| 2 | YZ |
| 3 | ABC |
| 3 | DEF |
| 3 | GHI |
| 3 | MNO |
| 3 | PQR |
| 3 | STU |
| 3 | VWX |
| 3 | YZ |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't said where you want the product list to come from. If you want all products by all locations you just need a cross join. If you want to filter the first half to a narrower set then that works too.

```
select productID, locationcode
from Products cross join Locations
except
select productID, locationcode
from LocationRestrictions
```